# Small Design Disliking

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

this is not another hate post (I personally, kinda like the new design...)

I've just noticed a very minor error (possibly?), when deleting my post this blue-on-red background was present, it was kind of distasteful:

[image: 1]

Now, there is also another (more important) error I found, it's the `image from url` popup:

[image]

Comment: What browser? What OS?

Comment: Does it on mine, Firefox 34.0 on Windows 8.1.  The "input.actual-edit-overlay" element is 777px wide.

Comment: If those *A* 's  were an answer I wonder what the question was....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for the close popup was not scoped quite right - this will be corrected in the next build.